# Alert or execute script, only if config file shows not in production mode

Tags: bash, inotify

I would like to test the software in development by running a particular script, say `script file.ext`. But I was told that I an not allowed to run the script if a config file, say `file.conf`, contains a particular string (not a comment with a leading #) which states the system is in production mode.

So in bash, how can I do something like

If `file1.conf` contain a string `in production` and that string is is not of the form  `something ... # something in production something` then execute `script file1.ext`.

Or, can I somehow get an alert every time the designated file contains the string `in production`, not in a comment?

I guess I need somehow use the command `inotifywait`. It would be also nice to have a script that not only checks the file `file1.conf` but alerts every time that some file with extension `.conf` shows I'm in a production mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to achieve this is with `grep`, e.g.,

```
grep "^[^#]* in production " file.conf || script file.ext
```

The part behind the `||` is only executed if the part before it does not exist with exit code 0 and `grep` has exit code 0 only if it finds its pattern (the first argument).

I chose a simple pattern `"^[^#]* in production "`. The character `^` stands for the beginning of the line, `[^#]` stands for any char except `#` and the quantifier `*` says there can be any number of them. The rest of the pattern is just the text you would expect to mark production mode.

In order to avoid all the output `grep` is producing you can send it to `/dev/null`:

```
grep "^[^#]* in production " file.conf > /dev/null || script file.ext
```

If you want to print a message, if you are in production mode and the script is not run you could do

```
grep "^[^#]* in production " file.conf > /dev/null && \
    echo "We are in production mode. The script was not run." || \
    script file.ext
```